# Is it possible to request GML using WFS-T for ZM type geometry? (Point ZM, LineString ZM, Polygon ZM)

Tags: elevation, gml, wfs-t, altitude

I'm a newbie here. I'm not sure whether my question is good or not...
But, I want to ask something.

To use Transactional Web Feature Service (WFS-T) to insert an object of a Point type, I sent a request in the form of Geographic Markup Language (GML).

Like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Insert>
        <feature:MyPointLayer xmlns:feature="http://your-namespace-uri">
            <geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <gml:coordinates>longitude latitude</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Point>
            </geom>
        </feature:MyPointLayer>
    </wfs:Insert>    
</wfs:Transaction>
```

But, Is it also possible to request WFS-T for ZM type geometry? (such as Point ZM, Multipolygon ZM etc...)
I mean the 3 dimension data, which contains altitude or elevation.

I requested same GML for ZM type, an error occurred like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://geo.dtwincloud.com/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
        <ows:ExceptionText>Error performing insert: Invalid output dimension (must be 2 or 3)</ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: You need only XYZ for 3-dimensional data. M is for measure. GML does not support measures in coordinates, they must be expressed as measure elements.